# While loop to solve additive persistence

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

After the first iteration of the while loop, the value of num becomes 29 with a length of 2 (you can see this by uncommenting out the print and break after the for loop).  Then the while loop should run again because the length of num is 2, but it actually becomes an infinite loop.  What I am missing?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String num = "9992";
    
    calculateAdditivePersistance(num);
}

public static void calculateAdditivePersistance( String num )
{
    int count   = 0;
    int total   = 0;
    
    while(num.length() > 1)
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < num.length(); x++)
        {
            total+= Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(x));
        }
        num = Integer.toString(total);
        //System.out.println(num); uncomment this out to see that num value becomes 29
        count++;
        //break;  uncomment this out to see that num value becomes 29
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you uncomment the println statement to see what is happening inside the loop?

Comment: You need to reset `total`, i.e. re-set it to zero, inside the `while` loop and before the `for` loop. Please look at this. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You are not resetting `total` inside your loop, so it accumulates the previous values of `num`, rather than just the current one.

Rather than resetting `total`, I recommend moving the declaration of `total` *inside* the `while` loop to fix this: as a general rule, you want to declare variables in the smallest possible scope.

Here’s a different approach to solving this problem, which treats numbers *as numbers* rather than treating them as strings of their decimal representation — this isn’t necessary a *better* solution but it illustrates that conversion to strings isn’t necessary.

```
static int additivePersistence(int num) {
    int count = 0;
    while (num > 9) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (num > 0) {
            sum += num % 10;
            num /= 10;
        }
        num = sum;
        count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This implementation also *returns* rather than prints the result. This is recommended: as a general rule, functions should *either* calculate *or* print something, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String num = "9992";
    
    calculateAdditivePersistance(num);
}

public static void calculateAdditivePersistance( String num )
{
    int count   = 0;
    int total   = 0;
    
    while(num.length() > 1)
    {
        total = 0;
        for( int x = 0; x < num.length(); x++)
        {
            total+= Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(x));
        }
        num = Integer.toString(total);
        //System.out.println(num); uncomment this out to see that num value becomes 29
        count++;
        //break;  uncomment this out to see that num value becomes 29
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Since you don't re-set `total`, it keeps getting bigger, rather than smaller. Therefore `num.length()` will **always** be greater than one.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the answer was that you weren't resetting total to 0.  But here is another approach that allows arbitrary length strings of digits `(up to their sum < Integer.MAX_VALUE)` and is relatively efficient in String conversion.

It works as follows:

- accept a string of integers.
- loop while length of the string is > 1 (i.e. more than a single digit).
- stream the characters and sum them by subtracting char 0 ('0') to convert to the `int` equivalent of the character
- convert back to a string and repeat.

The method returns a `List<String>` of transitions with the `size` of the list being the number of transitions.

```
String num = "99929222820283934829";

List<String> result = calculateAdditivePersistance(num);
System.out.println("Transitions = " + result);
System.out.println("Total transitions = " + result.size());
```

Prints

```
Transitions = [102, 3]
Total transitions = 2
```

The modified method.

```
    
public static List<String> calculateAdditivePersistance(String num) {
    List<String> conversions = new ArrayList<>();
    while(num.length() > 1) {
        num = num.chars().reduce(0, (a,b)->a + b-'0')+"";
        conversions.add(num);
    }
    return conversions;
}
```